# Magento form validation of hidden values

Tags: javascript, magento, prototype

I have problem with default Magento form validation. I'm using accordion for checkout page, so when I submit form, some fields are hidden. I noticed all hidden fields are passing validation, even if they are empty (required-entry class used). Is there any way to force validation script to check all fields, not only visible ones?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How would the user know and then change the hidden values if they are invalid?

Comment: Like I said, I'm using accordion. It's hiding fields located in inactive panels. User can access them by expanding collapsed panels and edit invalid values. I'm thinking about modifying default script to expand panel, where invalid values are located.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found answer here: http://awnist.com/blog/2011/05/02/overriding-magentos-form-error-mechanisms/

Basically you need to overwrite isVisible method for validated object to always return true from it. Load this JS code after loading /js/prototype/validation.js:

```
Object.extend(Validation, {
    isVisible : function(elm) {
        return true;
    },
    insertAdvice : function(elm, advice){
        // advice contains the div that would normally be inserted.
    }       
});
```

Overriding insertAdvice is optional - you can use it if you want to modify the way how validation advice is inserted.

Comment: Following the same line of thinking with your solution, using a `Function#wrap` call should allow you to call the parent method if you are only extending for specific scenarios ([ref](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/language/Function/prototype/wrap/)). eg: `Validation.prototype.isVisible = Validation.prototype.isVisible.wrap(parent, function(elm) { if (condition) return true; else return parent(elm); });`

Comment: i have a tab in my product detailed page, when i extend its worked for the current active tab only, how can i make to work for the all the other tab .